# AJAX multiple drop down list with price update

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax

can someone please help me with this code, i'm missing something but can't figure out what. When you select one of the items in the first list, it brings up the next box but there are no options to select and the same again with the 3rd option although i don't even get the box to appear this time.

I need about around 10 dropdown lists in total and after each selection has been selected to update the price at the bottom using the price column in the sql table ( I have no idea how to do this) so all your help will be great, been looking at this for at least 4 hours now and i'm getting no where.

Thanks

here is the html:

```
<body>
<select style="width: 150px;" name="country" id="add-event-dialog-country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
                <?php
                    echo "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'> Select Country</option>";
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM country");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                       echo "<option value='".$row['country']."'>".$row['country']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
           </select>
           <p id="statediv">
           <select style="width: 150px;" name="add-event-dialog-state" id="add-event-dialog-location" disabled="disabled">
                <option>Select State</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           <p id="citydiv">
           <select style="width: 150px;" name="add-event-dialog-city" id="add-event-dialog-city" disabled="disabled">
                <option>Select City</option>
           </select>
           </p>

Price =<br>
VAT = <br>
Total Price = <br>
</body>
```

Here's the js script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { 
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getState(country_Id) {     

    var strURL="findState.php?country="+country_Id;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}

function getCity(country_Id,state_id) {     

    var strURL="findCity.php?country_name="+country_Id+"&state_name="+state_Id;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
</script>
```

Here's the findState.php

```
<?php 
include 'classes.php';

$country = $_GET['country'];

$query="SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE country_id='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<select style="width: 150px;" id="add-event-dialog-location" name="add-event-dialog- location" onchange="getZone('<?=$country?>',this.value)">
<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Select State</option>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row['state_name']."'>".$row['state_name']."</option>";}
?>
</select>
```

Here's the findCity.php

```
<?php 
include 'classes.php';

$country_id = $_GET['country'];
$state_Id = $_GET['state'];

$query="SELECT city_name FROM city WHERE country_id='1' AND state_id='1'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<select style="width: 150px;" id="add-event-dialog-location" name="add-event-dialog- location" onchange="getZone('<?=$country?>',this.value)">
<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Select State</option>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row['city_name']."'>".$row['city_name']."</option>";}
?>
</select>
```

My SQL Database has 3 tables

1st table called country with 3 columns 
id, country and price

2nd table called state with 4 columns 
id, country_id, state_name and price

and 3rd table called city with 5 columns
id, country_id, state_id, city_name and price

Comment: Are your SQL queries running correctly and returning results as expected?

Comment: Hi weenoid, i think so, if i change $query="SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE country_id='$country'"; to $query="SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE country_id='1'"; it brings the selection up, it just won't work automatically when selecting through the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both findState.php and findCity.php you call the javascript function getZone when the selectlists changes? And I can't see that you have declared that function any where.

And you add both the state and city selectlist with the same id. I don't think that it is the cause of your problems, but it could be later on.

EDIT:

It seems you submit the country id in a variable called country_name but you try to access it in php by country and the same happens with findCity

EDIT 2:

Try changing your findstate.php to this

```
<?php 
include 'classes.php';

$country = $_GET['country'];

$query="SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE country_id='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$country = "'".$country."'";
echo '<select style="width: 150px;" id="add-event-dialog-location" name="add-event-dialog- location" onchange="getZone('.$country.',this.value)">';
echo "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Select State</option>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row['state_name']."'>".$row['state_name']."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The problem seems to be that php doesn't recognize that you are trying to insert the country id into the html select element. By echo'ing out everything this should be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the getZone was because i forgot to change it to getCity and then in the getCity.php it will have another. I didn't notice the double id, changed now but still have the issue.

Comment: Hi Falle  I changed what you mentioned but it hasn't made any difference. Just incase the part you mentioned was only on the second function, see below what i changed it do............. function getCity(country_Id,state_id) {     

    var strURL="findCity.php?country="+country_Id+"&state="+state_Id;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

Comment: Hi Falle, I've just copied and pasted your update into the findstate.php and it still acts the same, select the 1st drop list and the second one appears but just no data from sql

Comment: It seems to me that you expect an integer value as the country_id in findState.php, but it also seems as though you populate the country select-list with values that are strings containing the name of the countries. If that is the case you need to change echo "<option value='".$row['country']."'>".$row['country']."</option>";  to  echo "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'>".$row['country']."</option>";  or something similar.

Comment: Hi Falle, thanks for your time, i've looked into it a bit more and it seems to be something todo with.... $country = $_GET['country'];  .... if i change it to....  $country='1';   ..... would it be something todo with posting the form?

Comment: I think that the value you post from the first select list is the name of the country and not the id you expect. Could you try this for me: In you findState.php add this line:  echo "<h1>".$_GET['country']."</h1>";   This way we should be able to see what comes in to your findState.php page.

Comment: Hi Falle, done that and it displays what's been selected in the drop down list

Comment: And is that the same value as the one you use to select states in your database?

Comment: if i paste that in the findStates.php, it displays what was selected in the country drop down menu.

Comment: You need to change the values in the country selectlist to be the ids you need for selecting the states from the database. Something like  echo "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'>".$row['country']."</option>";      See the difference between whats in the value attribute and whats in the option-tag itself?

Comment: OK mate, got it working, after many hours I decided to copy: <?
include 'classes.php';
$query="SELECT id,country FROM country";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="country" onChange="getState(this.value)">
<option>Select Country</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['id']?>><?=$row['country']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>

Comment: What do you mean you by your last comment?

Comment: It's all working now, i pasted an update but it looks as though it's been taken down. Just copied the findCity.php dropdown box and pasted it in the html and changed a couple of things and it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help.